# Gitlab Ci gradlew: does not exist and --remove not passed

Tags: android, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I follow [this](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/10/24/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-android-projects/) link to implement a simple Gitlab ci in my sample project.
this is my Gitlab ci config

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "28"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "28.0.2"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS:   "4333796"

before_script:
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}.zip
  - unzip -d android-sdk-linux android-sdk.zip
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" >/dev/null
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" >/dev/null
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" >/dev/null
  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
  # temporarily disable checking for EPIPE error and use yes to accept all licenses
  - set +o pipefail
  - yes | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
  - set -o pipefail

stages:
  - build
  - test

lintDebug:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew -Pci --console=plain :app:lintDebug -PbuildDir=lint

assembleDebug:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/

debugTests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./gradlew -Pci --console=plain :app:testDebug
```

but it cannot find the gradlew and it always shows this error

```
$ chmod +x ./gradlew
chmod: cannot access './gradlew': No such file or directory
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: Is ./gradlew in your .gitignore file?


If you want to run ./gradlew, you must have it tracked in Git or generating/installing it in the before_script. Which does not seem like it is happening.

Comment: nice one, thanks, after adding gradlew and gradlew.bat and gradle folder to my git it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run `./gradlew`, you must have this file tracked in Git or generating/installing it in the before_script. Which does not seem like it is happening.

Most probably you aren't tracking the `gradlew` file, either by not adding it to Git, or by ignoring it in a `.gitignore` file.
Make sure you are tracking `gradlew` file in your VCS.

Answer (score 0):

In your `variables`, add this:
`ANDROID_GRADLE_VERSION: "gradle-5.1.1"`

And in your `before_script`, add this before `chmod +x ./gradlew`:

```
- wget --quiet --output-document=gradle.zip https://services.gradle.org/distributions/${ANDROID_GRADLE_VERSION}-bin.zip
- unzip -q gradle.zip
```